# Is markdown enabled by default in python notebooks?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

This would seem to be a very simple /obvious question - but I can not find an answer.

I placed a `markdown` fragment in the first cell of a `python2` kernel `jupyter` notebook:

[image]

As we can see it was not rendered ..  Is there some silly/simple step required to enable markdown?

Comment: @rayryeng  pls make this an answer. ah you did !  will award when the timer gets down to 0

Comment: No problem at all. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  What you have right now is a code block and it's commenting out that line that you've made.

You can tell it's a code block due to the `In [3]:` demarcation to the left meaning that it is the third statement you have run in the notebook since the Python kernel started.  If it were Markdown, there would be no indication of that to the left. Running the cell in this case does nothing because there is no code to run.

To turn it into a Markdown cell, you have to go to the Cell menu option at the top and turn it into one. By default, every cell you make is a code block.  Failing that, select the cell and push the <kbd>M</kbd> key as the shortcut to turn it into Markdown. Push the <kbd>Y</kbd> key to turn it back into a code block.

A great reference to use for later on is this link: http://maxmelnick.com/2016/04/19/python-beginner-tips-and-tricks.html.  It contains all of the shortcuts you need for making Jupyter notebooks quickly such as deleting a cell, creating a new cell, switching between Markdown and code cells and so forth.